# Why does new Date().setHours(18) return a number instead of a date?

Tags: javascript, date, typescript, ionic2

Why do the first line of code return an object of type "Date" whereas the second one returns a "number" ?

According to the doc (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sethours.asp) setHours() should just change the value of the hour of the date object, not convert it.

The code :

```
  var date = new Date();

  var date2 =date.setHours(19);
```

Thanks !

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours Check out the docs. It sets the hours for the specified date, AND returns the timestamp.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours

Comment: Look at the actual value of the `date` object... you'll see that it's set as you specified.

Comment: Also agree that this is a little weird they decided to do this. I stop using date and just started to use timestamps all together instead...

Comment: Thanks, it was not clear in my link. Is there a way to set the hour and keep a date object ?

Comment: @Krowar — Yes. Just don't overwrite the `date` object you already have. i.e. do exactly what you are doing (or you could discard the return value entirely instead of storing it in `date2`).

Comment: @Krowar It doesn't stop being a date object just because it has a different return value. Just calle `date.setHours(19)` without assignign the return value.

Answer (score 8):

You need to wrap your answer in `new Date()`. Like this:

```
var date2 = new Date(date.setHours(19));
```

Answer (score 3):

The setHours() method sets the hours for a specified date according to local time, and returns the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC until the time represented by the updated Date instance.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours

Answer (score 2):

> According to the doc (`http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sethours.asp`) setHours() should just change the value of the hour of the date object, not convert it.

That document says:

> Return Value: A Number, representing the number of milliseconds between the date object and midnight January 1 1970

It doesn't *convert* the date object though. It modifies the existing one and then returns a value.

The date object you created before still exists, with the modified hour value, and any references to it (like the one you still have in the variable named `date`) will remain available.

Comment: This answer should reference either [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.sethours) or [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours).

Comment: @RobG — While W3Schools has plenty of problems, it is correct here, and it is the documentation the OP was already reading.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple, just read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) about it.

See below what that method returns.

> Return value
>
> The number of milliseconds between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and the
>   updated date.

Answer (score 0):

I came here because I got a `date.getTime is not a function` error from Firebase Cloud Functions. 
It is important to remember that `setHours()` returns a timestamp (number) AND modifies the date object (date).

For Firebase users who want to use the firebase timestamp and `setHours()` method:

```
// import Timestamp
const { Timestamp } = require('firebase-admin/firestore');

// create a new date object and reset the time to 00:00 (to sort or compare just by days, not by time/hours)
const dateForQuery = new Date();
dateForQuery.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

// setHours returns a timestamp, but it also modifies the date object. At this point, dateForQuery is already modified and we don't need to wrap it again in a new Date().
...
dateCreated: Timestamp.fromDate(dateForQuery),
...
```